# It seems laptop aspire 5742 is damaging Hard drives

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, freeze

The laptop started rebooting itself and going into recovery mode and failing to recover, I tried the hdd on another computer and WD diagnose tool failed, so I bought a new WD blue 500gb HDD, I installed win 7 and the laptop worked well. After one week of use the laptop started with the same problem, took the hdd and plugged it into a pc, it was recognised by the BIOS but it wouldnt let me make a fresh install of either ubuntu or Win 7, both OS freeze on the installation process, on Win 7 it freezes after selecting country, keyboard and time and on Linux it freezes after selecting ok on the first panel.

I tried a 80gb hdd and it worked well for a few minutes but, I'm scared it would broke again..

I have never seen a laptop damaging HDD is it possible?

How can I fix it?

I dont have warranty..

Comment: I suppose its possible.  Unless you are doing something with the laptop while its reading/writting to the HDD you shouldn't its very unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that your motherboard is failing. This may be causing incorrect amount of voltage to be heading to the hard drive or telling it to read excessively. Most likely a power issue as the HDD's would not fail from too much reading that quickly. I suggest either replacing the laptop or the motherboard (which is generally more expensive than a new cheap laptop).